# Count records in table which contain given items

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've a query which should count all the movies which contain the given genres.

The query works but it query's the link table for each movie in the database which results in a 1 minute and 6 second load time.

The table structure looks like the following:

**Movie**
Contains all the movies

**Genre**
Contains all the names of the genres

**MovieGenre**
Each record in this table contains a movie id and genre name.

```
 public async Task<int> CountMovies(List<string> pGenres)
    {
        return await (
            from movie in Context.Movie
            join genre in Context.MovieGenre on movie.MovieId equals genre.MovieId into genres
            where pGenres.All(pGenre => genres.Any(genre => genre.GenreName == pGenre))
            select movie
        ).CountAsync();
    }
```

How can I prevent round trips to the server and do everything in the database?

The code above results in 108 round trips to the database, for example:

```
SELECT [genre0].[genre_name],[genre0].[movie_id]
FROM [Movie_Genre] AS [genre0]
WHERE 353 /* @_outer_MovieId */ = [genre0].[movie_id]
```

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: @octavioccl EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.2

Comment: Consider using PredicateBuilder from LINQKit to create or conditions for your `pGenres`. And isn't your query wrong for finding a movie containing all members of `pGenres`? It looks to me like it finds movies that only have genres in `pGenres`, and excludes movies that have additional genres.

Comment: Could you please explain here where is round trip as till genres it will be just a single call to DB? and also can you check AsEnumerable() so where clause will execute at object level perf will be sligtly improve?

Answer (score 0):

First insert your list of genres into a temporary table, then join to that

Answer (score 0):

if the Type of `Context.MovieGenre` is `MovieGenres`, and it contains a collection of individual `MovieGenre` objects, then add an extension method:

```
int CountMoviesWithGenre(this MovieGenres mg, List<string> genreNames)
{
    return mg
       .Where(mg=>genreNames.Contains(mg.GenreName,
                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
       .Select(m => m.MovieId)
       .Distinct()
       .Count();
}
```

call it like this:

```
var genNames = new List<string> {"Horror", "Suspense","Action"};
var count = Context.MovieGenre.CountMoviesWithGenre(genNames);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, MovieGenres doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

EF Core still have some issues translating complex queries to sql, it has a mix of server execution with client execution, and there is something in your query that is being executed in the client side. Instead of execute a `count(*)` is loading all the data of the selected movies. To try to improve your query, try the following:

```
return await Context.MovieGenre.GroupBy(e=>e.MovieId,e=>e.GenreName)
                               .Where(g=>pGenres.All(pGenre => g.Contains(pGenre)))
                               .CountAsync();
```

The main issue is the `Where` condition, you could also try the following:

```
  return await Context.MovieGenre.Where(g=>pGenres.Contains(g.GenreName))
                                 .GroupBy(e=>e.MovieId,e=>e.GenreName)
                                 .Where(g=>pGenres.Count==g.Count())
                                 .CountAsync();
```

Comment: This results in 108 round trips back to the database. The pGenres is still causing an issue here.

Comment: @Jamie, could you try the new query I posted

Comment: Yes sorry. 64 round trips. So you have improved it by a lot. But it still takes like 32 seconds to load.  It's still doing the select from moviegenre. Honestly, i don't think it's possible to prevent these round trips.

Comment: Try with my second query maybe we have lucky this time ;)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I now get a timeout exception

Comment: Thanks for trying though, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm done.

```
        public async Task<int> CountMovies(List<string> pGenres, int? year, decimal? minPrice,
        decimal? maxPrice)
    {
        using (var command = Context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = $"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Movie.movie_id) from Movie_Genre join Movie on Movie.movie_id = Movie_Genre.movie_id where genre_name in ('Action', 'Adult')";
            Context.Database.OpenConnection();
            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                await result.ReadAsync();
                int amount = result.GetInt32(0);
                Context.Database.CloseConnection();
                return amount;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this have the same problem of selecting movies with either Action or Adult genres and not just movies that have both?

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick I've seen/used recently is counting can you tell you a lot:

```
public async Task<int> CountMovies(List<string> pGenres) {
    return await (
        from movie in Context.Movie
        join genre in Context.MovieGenre on movie.MovieId equals genre.MovieId into genres
        where genres.Where(genre => pGenres.Contains(genre.GenreName)).Count() == pGenres.Count()
        select movie
    ).CountAsync();
}
```

Comment: The answer from octavioccl does the same. It has a lot of round trips because of the where clause.

Comment: When I do this with LINQ to SQL on my database, the `.Contains` is converted to an `IN` in SQL and only one query is executed.

Answer (score -1):

It is one trip and return all movies that at least contain one of pGeners.

```
var moviesCount = Context.MovieGenre
             .Where(x => pGenres.Contains(x.GenreName))
             .Select(x => x.Movie).Distinct().ToList().Count();
```

Comment: That selects movies that have any one of `pGenres`, not movies that have all of `pGenres`.

Comment: @Milney The query return the movies that have any one of pGenres. Check it first

Comment: @Saeid My point was he was asking to avoid using the local collection as it then can't be sent as one query... your answer doesn't address that atall

Comment: @Milney It is absolutely one trip to DB, you just leave the comments before even test it, The contain in C# translate to *IN* in SQL

Comment: It indeed doesn't do any round trips but like @NetMage said. It doesn't select movies which contain all pGenres.